# Prove that $T$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is the full question:

Let $T$ be an operator on $V$. Prove that if $T^2=2I$, then $T$ is invertible.

I am completely stumped, the only thing I can kind of see is...

Let $v$ be an element of $V$. Then $T^2v = 2Iv$, thus $T^2v-2Iv=0$ and it follows that $(T^2-2I)v=0$, thus 2 is an eigenvalue of $T^2$.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Is $V$ a finite-dimensional vector space?

Comment: Assume $T$ is not injective: say $Tv=0$ for some $v$. What can you say about $T^2v$ ?  About surjectivity:  Take $w$\in V$.  We are given $T^2w =w$ How is $T62$ computed on a $w$ in terms of $T$?

Answer (score 7):

If $T^2=2I$, $T^{-1}=\dfrac12 T$, by definition.

Comment: As long as $\operatorname{char}K\neq 2$ ;)

Comment: I supposed the O.P. was working with $\mathbf R$. But you're right, strictly speaking, it must be added.